# application runs but no app icon in emulator

Tags: android, webview, android-xml

In my code I have a webview. the code runs and shows the web content.But after pressing the backward key in emulator i can not see the app icon in it for reopening. the logcat shows the following error also

**WebActivity.java**

```
package example.webapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }
    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**logcat**

```
08-22 17:53:11.464: E/geolocationService(278): Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree. please give me an answer
```

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.webapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="example.webapp.WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.